# C# - Global Program Object

Tags: c#, oop, static

#### Scenario

I have a non-static class that wraps around Log4Net. This is really handy as it links up to a further application I have that displays logs of different processes that occur in a variety of software that I write (to allow me to see where errors occur, batch processes fail etc.)

#### Problem

This is all well and good, but if I want to log an entire process, I have to do a series of things:

1. Instantiate the Logging object.
2. Tell it to begin.
3. Log stuff.
4. Tell it to stop.

This means that if a process runs outside of the class I have to mess about passing the Logging object around which is a pain and looks messy.

#### Question

How can I essentially just declare the object in such a way that It is globally accessible by all the classes......and making it static isn't really an option, I don't think.

.....This could be a waste of time but I like opinions.

Comment: Why isn't making the wrapper static an option?  This is exactly a case where a static class would make sense.

Answer (score 6):

Why do you believe that making "it" static isn't an option? I suspect you're confusing the ideas of a static *class* and a static *variable* which maintains a reference to an instance of a non-static class.

```
public class Foo
{
    // Instantiate here, or somewhere else
    private static LogWrapper logWrapper = new LogWrapper(...); 
    public static LogWrapper LogWrapper { get { return logWrapper; } }
}
```

Just because the *class* is non-static doesn't mean you can't have a singleton instance of it which is globally available. Normally not such a good idea, but not too bad for logging.

If you *do* go down the singleton route, you may want to consider reading my article on [implementing a singleton in C#](http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/singleton.html).

Comment: I think he meant making the entire class static.

Comment: @Slaks: And my point is that he doesn't have to. It's important to differentiate between a static class and a non-static class with an instance which is globally available. (That doesn't mean it *has* to be a singleton, but it might.)

Comment: I realize that; that's my point too. However, it sounds from your first line like you may have misunderstood him.

Answer (score 5):

It sounds like you want a [singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern).

You can make a static property that returns the single instance of your class.

Answer (score 4):

Rather than going down the static path or the Singleton path, you could investigate using [Dependency Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) (DI) with an [IoC Container framework](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ListOfNETDependencyInjectionContainersIOC.aspx). This would keep your classes testable and would decouple them from the logging class.

The IoC Container will handle lifetime management for you; by specifying container lifetime, you can simulate a Singleton with none of the disadvantages.

There is a learning curve, but it's worth it; DI has many other advantages.

EDIT: The trick is to avoid the Service Locator trap. [Mark Seemann](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/01/25/DependencyInjectionInversionInNET.aspx) has some nice articles on this (and a book coming out).